# C++ receive function return by reference

Tags: c++, reference

Let's say we have a function

```
int increment(int x) {
  return x+1;
}
```

Does it make any different to receive the return value by

```
const int foo = increment(8);
```

OR

```
const int& foo = increment(8);
```

?

What if a return type is a more complex and more sizable object? Does it make sense to use a reference to avoid an unnecessary copy?

I thought the returned value is out of the scope of the function (`increment` in this example). So that one copy is needed anyway. Correct?

Comment: There is no copy in the first example, thanks to RVO (mandatory since C++17). With C++17, returning by value works even if the return type is a class with no copy or move constructor. The second approach is technically valid but pointless.

Comment: `int increment(x)` - I assume you meant: `int increment(int x)` ?

Comment: Thanks Igor. You mean there is no copy for both examples (reference or not), since c++ 17. Correct? How about pre-C++17? Say C++11.

Comment: @selbie You're right.

Comment: C++98 already allowed RVO. All mainstream compilers implemented RVO since approximately forever. C++17 merely codified existing practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make any different to receive the return value by ...

It doesn't make a difference in the sense that both have the same observable behaviour.

It does subjectively make difference in the sense that using the reference is more complex, and its understanding requires knowledge of more language rules. Lifetime extension of temporaries is a somewhat obscure language rule that is poorly understood by beginners as far as I know.

> What if a return type is a more complex and more sizable object?

Doesn't matter.

> Does it make sense to use a reference to avoid an unnecessary copy?

No copy is avoided. Instead of the local variable, the reference version creates a temporary object and the reference is bound to the temporary. It doesn't make sense to use a reference here.

Comment: There would be different observable behaviour in the case of `decltype(foo)`